# Unknown Username

Tags: centos

I inherited a backup server running centOS 5. We recently went from a Windows Server System to a NAS System. No one knows what the username is or the password and I need to know these before I can set up the backup server on the NAS System. I have found a way to change the password to something I know and that has been done, but I still need to know how to change the username to something I know before I can set it up on the NAS and use it to backup all the computers and the NAS on our office network. Can anyone help me out?
Ray

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the machine? root or just a way to log in as the unknown user? In the latter case, `who am i` might be your friend.

Comment: I can reboot it and then it goes straight to the log in screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy actually, first of all get a linux machine and add a user with a password. Then look at `/etc/shadow` look for the username, it has a very long hash behind it, copy it.

Now boot a live disk on your centOS machine and mount the disks. Look for the user in the centOS's `/etc/shadow` file, replace that hash with the hash you generated before. So now you know:

- username (saw it in the /etc/shadow file)
- password (it's the one you generated)

Comment: This is the only linux machine that we have, do i have to use a second machine running linux?

Comment: just get a live disk

Comment: `/etc/shadow` would have the password hash, not `/etc/passwd`. You can tell because the lines in `/etc/passwd` will end with a `*` or a `x`.

Comment: oops, fixed that :)

Answer (score 0):

Anther way is to boot into recovery mode:
[(link)](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html)
and check the /etc/passwd for username, and change the password for it with :

```
passwd <username>
```